In VSCode: No floating documentation when hovering over Java Standard Library method
In VSCode, whenever I hover my mouse over a method of a Class from the Java "Standard Library" it doesn't show the documentation of that method. Though, when hovering over the corresponding class, it shows Documentation.
For example, hovering above java.lang.Character.toUpperCase() gets me this
When I now hover above java.lang.Character it shows me some Documentation, so I guess at least something is working. Hovering over Chracter Class
Weirdly enough, whenever I restart VSCode and immediately put my mouse above a method, it shows me the Documentation. But as soon as VSCode is fully loaded, the next time I hover above the same method, it gets replaced with the above behavior. Hovering over method and it works
I'm running Ubuntu in WSL2 on Windows 11. Following Extensions are installed inside WSL:

Debugger for Java
Extension Pack for Java
Gradle for Java
IntelliCode
IntelliCode API Usage Examples
Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
Maven for Java
Project Manager for Java
Test Runner for Java

I installed OpenJDK 21, including the source and doc packages with apt-get.
My JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/
In my settings.json (Remote) I added following lines:
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "OpenJDK-21",
            "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64",
            "sources": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/lib/src.zip",
            "javadoc": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/docs/api",
            "default": true
        },
    ]


I actually found a solution by myself.
Firstly I noticed a mistake in my settings.json (Remote). The name attribute was set to OpenJDK-21, which was wrong. The correct accepted value is JavaSE-21.
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-21",
        ...
    },
]

Secondly, I think the true fix was to set the correct JDK inside the Java Project Settings. I accessed these by clicking Java: Ready in the bottom toolbar, then choose Open Project Settings and switch to the correct JDK in JDK Runtime-tab.
Hope it helps someone in the future!
